# errors when trying to create a function copy during explicit initialization

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I unable to understand the error that i am getting in a template-class program.

**CODE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

template <class dataType> class myClass {
public:
void function();
};

template<> class myClass<int> {
public:
void expli_function();
};

template <class dataType> void myClass<dataType>::function() {
cout << "Not an explicit function !" << endl;
}

template <class int> void myClass<int>::expli_function() { //<-- while pointing towards errors compiler points here
cout << "Explicit function !" << endl;
}

int main() {
myClass<string> ob1;
myClass<int> ob2;
ob1.function();
ob2.expli_function();
}
```

The errors are:

```
tester_1.cpp(20): error C2332: 'class' : missing tag name
tester_1.cpp(20): error C2628: '<unnamed-tag>' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
tester_1.cpp(20): error C2993: '' : illegal type for non-type template parameter '<unnamed-tag>'
error C2244: 'myClass<int>::expli_function' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
```

Why do i get these errors and how can i solve them ?

Answer (score 5):

This fixes it :

```
void myClass<int>::expli_function() {
    cout << "Explicit function !" << endl;
}
```

Since the `class myClass<int>` is a specialization, it doesn't need `template<int>` keyword before defining the function method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what VJo has said.

You dont need to template a function definition for a (unique) specialization. i.e.

```
void myClass<int>::expli_function() { //<-- while pointing towards errors compiler points here
cout << "Explicit function !" << endl;
}
```

will define expli_function() for the class that resolves to `myClass<int>`.

edit: too late! he has made more edits :)